# Checking if there're equal bits in binary string

Tags: algorithm, random

We have 2 binary strings: X and Y, in 2 different computers. Both of them in length n. The computers can communicate by sending bits to each other.

We have to build randomized algorithm to check whether there's an index i such that Xi=Yi. We can send only O(log n) bits between the computers.

If there's no such index the algorithm will always return "false". If there's such index, the algorithm will return "true" in probability 0.5 (at least).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What makes you think this is possible? The "If there's no such index the algorithm will always return `false`." part sounds unlikely to me. I don't think you can determine that A XOR B = 0 with only O(log n) communication

Comment: First of all, if there's no such index so for all i: if Xi = 1 then Yi = 0, and if Xi = 0 then Yi = 1. So if such an index doesn't exist A XOR B is n bits of 1.
Secondly, as I wrote in a comment below, you can do any manipulation on X before sending information for computer 2. You can send any information of O(log n) bits you want. It doesn't have to be a part of X. Similarly, after computer 2 gets the O(log n) information, it can make also manipulation on it (and also on Y) before returning 0 or 1 (for "true" or "false").

Comment: Did you try to search with keywords such as "set disjointness communication complexity"?

Comment: Niklas B.: "If there's no such index the algorithm will always return false." - easy! just return `false` every time :) Or more usefully - assume that the two strings are the same by default. Then if you (by 50% chance) make sure that they are not return `true`.

Comment: @stanm Yeah I realized there is a huge fault in my comment. Still I don't believe a solution exists, especially because `O(log n)` is just arbitrary. Why not O(n^(1/2)) or any other function of n? The only hope I have is *maybe* if X and Y are assumed to be distributed uniformly and at random, rather than given. Because then you can just select a random bit and send it over.

Comment: Because you have to return false if there is no index, then you must have a way to definitively prove that there is no such index. If you can prove that there is no such index, then you can prove that there *is* such an index. So the 50% probability thing seems like a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

If the bits are independent sending any `log(n)` will give you the same chance that you 'hit' the equal bits. You will not be able to improve this without any additional information.

Comment: You can send through a count of the bits in `O(log n)` - I'm inclined to think you can use this (and `O(log n) != log n`).

Comment: @Dukeling I am not sure what do you mean with the first sentence. As with the second part that is true, but it does not change the validity of my answer.(same will hold true for `2 * log(n)`, though)

Comment: For `1001010001010`, you can possibly just send through `5 = 101`, so you can check whether corresponding parts have the same number of bits set. Admittedly this doesn't tell you *where* these bits are, but perhaps that's where the probabilistic part comes in. Either way, I'm not particularly convinced whether this is or isn't possible yet.

Comment: You don't have to send a part of the string. You can do any manipulation you want on computer 1 before sending data to computer 2.
Computer 2 can also make manipulations on its string, and also on the O(log n) string he has (which can be a number representing some answer of manipulation on X, and not part of X itself).

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit on Ivaylo's answer:

imagine the two strings are

```
A = 110110....0....00010
B = 001001....0....11101
```

both are of some large length n, and Ak = Bk for a single k, somewhere in the middle.

You basically want functions that transform A, or B, such that f(A) and g(B) are `O(log n)` bit numbers. E.g. sum is such a function.

Say you sum the bits of A, i.e. `f = sum`. Also let `g = sum . xor`.

So if A was `110110 0 00010 (12 bits)` and B was `001001 0 11101 (12 bits)`, then f(A) = `5 / 101 (3 bits)` and `g(B) = 6 / 110 (3 bits)`. You can compare them and since they are different so you can say "Aha! Then the numbers must share a bit! (there must be i, s.t. Ai = Bi)" and you will be right. However, while this is enough evidence, it is not necessary true when the answer should be true. In other words: there could be i s.t. Ai = Bi, but f(A) = g(B).

Lets look closer to the functions to see why. f(A) really counts how many ones there are in A, g(B) counts how many zeroes there are in B. Assuming that if they are the same then A XOR B = 0, is the same as saying "any number that has as many zeros as there are ones in another number results in 0 when XOR-ed with that other number." Which is false: 100 and 110 fulfill the condition but 100 XOR 110 is 010.

Now you can say: "Well, we just need to pick better f and g." However, the reason sum didn't work is fundamental and you cannot get away from it: f and g are hash-functions, or in maths language - [surjective functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function). The domain has size of O(n) bits or O(2^n) elements, while the codomain (target set) has size of O(log n) bits or O(2 ^ (log n)) = O(n) elements and O(2^n) > O(n).

Surjective functions cannot be inverted (which is what you actually want). Any time you invert f(A) or g(B) you get one-to-many mapping. If f(A) is 2 and A has 3 bits, then A could be {110, 101, 011}. The size of the **inverse image** of f(A) would be, on average, O(2^n / n). With **no further information** the chance of you guessing the value of A is O(n / 2^n) < 0.5 in the general case.

And you have **no further information**, because if you did, you could incorporate it in f and g, but that would increase the size of their codomain.

I suggest reading up on [information theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) for further understanding of information loss, entropy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

for stanm (I wrote it as an answer because comment was to long):
It's a correct solution. The full algorithm is:

1. k = number of 1's in X.
2. Send k to computer 2.
3. l = number of 0's in Y.
4. If k=l computer 2 will answer "no", else "yes" (or 0 and 1).

If there's no index i such that Xi=Yi, so the algorithms will always answer "no" (or 0).
If such index exists. The probability for computer 2 for wrong answer is the probability that computer 2 will get l=k.
The number of all binary strings (length n) that contains k 0's is (n choose k).
The number of all binary strings (length n) is (2^n).
So the probability that computer 2 will fail even though it has to return "yes" is (n choose k)/2^n. You can prove that this number is always less than (or equal to) 1/2.

So finally we can conclude that:

If such an index doesn't exists computer 2 will answer "no". If it exists, so the probability that computer 2 will fail is less than (or equal to) 1/2, and therefore it will answer "yes" in probability more than 1/2.