# Randomized algorithm in matrices

Tags: algorithm, random, matrix

We have 2 computers. Comp1 and Comp2 hold binary matrices A and B of size NxN respectively.

We want to check if the matrices of the computers are identical except for exactly 1 entry.

Comp1 has to send O(n*log^2(n)) message to Comp2 and Comp2 should and 0 or 1 (for "no" and "yes" respectively) with the answer.

If the matrices differ with exactly 1 entry, Comp2 will answer 1 ("yes") always.

If they don't differ with exactly 1 entry, Comp2 will answer 0 in probability of at least 0.5.

Both computers can make any manipulation of their matrix before sending a message. Comp1 of course don't have to send a part of its matrix. It can send an answer of computation on its matrix, and Comp2 can make also any calculation it wants before answering.

I've tried to solve it but whatever I tried it failed.

Comment: Where is the random element? And why are you trying to do this at all? It doesn't sound like much of a real world problem to me...

Comment: The random element is that Comp2 may answer "yes" although it should answer "no". If it sould answer "no", he'll do that in probability of at least 1/2.

Comment: So is this a puzzle rather than a programming problem? If so I noticed http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/ recently which may be a more appropriate place to post this. This doesn't seem to be a situation you'd find in the real world so I suspect it may be off topic (though I'm not sure enough to vote to close as such).

Comment: This is more like a communication complexity problem. Did you try http://cs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: This problem is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081203/checking-if-therere-equal-bits-in-binary-string#comment37148461_24081203. The primary difference being that this problem allows sending O(n log^2 n) bytes, and the other allows sending only O(log n) bytes. Neither of the problems is well specified. A reference to the original problem would be very useful.

Comment: I understand that I can think of a matrix as a binary string of length n^2. But the main difference is that here I want to check if the strings differ in exactly 1 index. In your link we wanted to check if there's an index of equality, so I don't unserstand how to use the previous problem in order to solve this one.

Comment: @JimMischel, You probably won't be able to read the original problem, unless you know Hebrew. This a part of a homework assignment in an Algorithms course @ Ben-Gurion University (BTW, the question you link to, is another question of the same assignment).